# TypeScript export and rename default

Tags: typescript

```
interface Foo {
  hello(): string;
}

export default Foo;
```

Suppose I want to *rename* it to `Bar`. Then I must do this:

```
export {Foo as Bar};    // notice there is no `default`
```

How do I rename and use `default` at the same time?

Comment: The name for the default does not matter, When importing the client can use any name they want (not my downvote)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Thanks. That is true - but then why do we have the ability to rename?

Comment: For non default exports :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For default exports the name does not matter. When importing the client code can specify whatever name they want for the import

```
import BarOrWhatever from './Bar'
```

The ability to rename exports is there when you want to re-export non-default exports.